# Screenshooting a wpf control from asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, wpf, asp.net-mvc

I have a smll web solution where i allow usres to upload small wpf controls to be saved for later use, one of the things i want to do is make a screenshot of the wpf components being uploaded. Im using asp.net mvc and looked into the RenderTargetBitmap, but cant seem to get it to work. - My first problem is adding the reference to "system.windows.media" to an asp.net mvc solution.

Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible, cannot render a STA WPF control in a web environment. Created a STA thread and tried, showed up "black" screenshot, was not rendered.